# Resizing Window Form control

Tags: vb.net, winforms

My problem is that I am unable to resize the form control according to the form size.
I have a form which contains a textbox, a label and a button. On button click I need to open the same form in a particular sized window and I want all the controls of the form should be proportional with the form and the font size inside the control should be proportional too. Can anybody please suggest how to do that with code. Unable to solve this by using the anchor and dock property.

My code:

```
Private Sub Test_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim widthRatio As Single = Me.Size.Width / 300.0F
    Dim heightRatio As Single = Me.Size.Height / 300.0F
    Dim scale As New SizeF(widthRatio, heightRatio)
    Me.Scale(scale)
    For Each control As Control In Me.Controls
        control.Scale(scale)
        control.Font = New Font(control.Font.FontFamily,   control.Font.SizeInPoints * widthRatio * heightRatio)
    Next
End Sub
```

here for width and height ratio I have divided 300.0F because my original form is size(300,300), but I am not getting all the controls expand equally... any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

pallavi

Comment: Don't call Scale to resize the control, set it's Size property to the new Size instead.

Comment: Change the Font property of the form instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check these two lines

```
Dim widthRatio As Single = Me.Size.Width / 300.0F
Dim heightRatio As Single = Me.Size.Height / 300.0F
```

in your case Me.Size.Width = 300 and Me.Size.Height = 300 that's why its not working, change width or height then check it

Comment: have u changed the values(Height/Width) to other than 300.0 right?,     control.Font.SizeInPoints * widthRatio * heightRatio is giving small difference check with "DEBUG"

Comment: yes i hv set it to 400 and 500(width and height respectively)..
control.Font.SizeInPoints=8.25 initially
widthRatio =1.333
heightRatio =1.666
for this its working fine but whn the width and height becomes(600,300) then height is not adjusting properly for the button...means the font of the button increases but not the height of the button accordingly

Comment: @user1740857, then you need to work(Change the concept) on the control.Font.SizeInPoints * widthRatio * heightRatio